# Contrary to RestSharp docs, request.AddFile does not accept FileParameter as argument for AddFile. Can't find any docs on how to migrate. Any ideas?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http, restsharp

Ok so here's the C# code that's breaking since I updated RestSharp to the current version:

```
restRequest.Files.Add((FileParameter)file); // Added cast for clarity
```

According to the the [current official documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#uploading-files), this is the correct alternative:

```
restRequest.AddFile((FileParameter)file);
```

However, that appears to be incorrect, as it throws this exception:

> No overload for method 'AddFile' takes 1 arguments

This directly contradicts the RestSharp docs.  I haven't been able to find any way to get around this.  I tried the overloads that are there but FileParameter no longer contains the Writer property which would be required and I can't find any docs mentioning where that was moved to.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like `AddFile` you want is `internal`  now (https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/39e6e7d4460e4d37fc36cb40c970364d5736acaf/src/RestSharp/Request/RestRequest.cs#L201). You can find other available overloads here (https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/ebb1df1cb919466e6490175afb028a16e262ac40/src/RestSharp/Request/RestRequestExtensions.cs#L272). There is also inline docs present.

Comment: Yeah there are 3 available but none of them will accept a FileParameter, nor am I able to figure out how to convert a FileParameter to byte[] or whatever else.  If they're going to make so many frequent BC breaking changes, I wish they'd at least put some effort into documenting them.

Comment: "... nor am I able to figure out how to convert a FileParameter to byte[]" - The extension methods are available that take, say for instance, a byte array or a Stream. You can read the contents of the file and pass them to one of these extensions, which then creates internally, a `FileParameter` type. Unless, I am missing something, why do you want to convert `FileParameter` to `byte[]` explicitly (yes, I acknowledge the fact this is a breaking change)?

Comment: `FileParameter.Create` has the same signature of `AddFile` method. Maybe you simply need a step back

Comment: The link for the document opens the documentation for v107. Make sure you are using this version. It might be a change in the signature of the methods, from one version to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`restRequest.Files` is [readonly collection](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/restsharp/RestSharp/39e6e7d4460e4d37fc36cb40c970364d5736acaf/src/RestSharp/Request/RestRequest.cs) so you cannot use that property to add more files.

[image: readonly restsharp collection files]

Since the overload `restRequest.AddFile((FileParameter)file);` is not there in the newer version of restsharp, you can define your own extension method like this:

```
using RestSharp;

public static class RestRequestExtensions
{
    public static RestRequest AddFile(this RestRequest req, FileParameter f)
    {
        return req.AddFile(f.Name, GetBytes(f.GetFile()), f.FileName, f.ContentType);
    }

    private static byte[] GetBytes(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Another way:

```
public static class RestRequestExtensions
{
    public static RestRequest AddFile(this RestRequest req, FileParameter f)
    {
        return req.AddFile(f.Name, ()=>f.GetFile(), f.FileName, f.ContentType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it caused the server to reject the image as invalid (not sure the details, just an API response).   The overload does seem to work in that I am seeing the image data in the RestRequest object, but it's in a different place than in previous versions.  So I don't know if this is a RestSharp bug or what.

Comment: Reported the issue here:  https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1881

Comment: Oh and FYI I do plan to mark this as the accepted answer.  I just need to be able to confirm it, which I can do once this other issue stops blocking my tests from passing.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue as well (restsharp 108.0.1) while working with an api integration. I was able to get around the issue by adding my file into the request body.

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes({your filePath});

//request setup...

restRequest.AddBody(fileBytes, {your fileType});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AddFile(FileParameter)` has been marked as `internal` as commented by @Serg, so `request.AddFile(fileParameter);` will not work in later version unless they remove the `internal` modifier again.

As to the `Action<Stream> Writer` property of `FileParameter`, now it becomes `Func<Stream> GetFile`. To specify your own `GetFile`, you could call this extension method

```
AddFile(parameterName, getFile, fileName, contentType);
```

which will call the `internal AddFile(FileParameter)` using the specified `GetFile`:

```
RestRequest.AddFile(FileParameter.Create(name, getFile, fileName, contentType))
```

It would be a bit confusing that old versions is `Action<Stream>` where the library will pass the `Stream` to your `Writer` and now you need to pass the `Stream` to the library via `GetFile`.